# How to keep time series original dates in rugarch R package?

Tags: r, time-series

In R, I have a time series object (ts)

```
library(rugarch)
library(TSA)

observations <- read.csv("financial_data.csv", header = TRUE)
start = c(1999, as.numeric(format(as.Date("1999-05-19"), "%j")))
end = c(2003, as.numeric(format(as.Date("2003-10-04"), "%j")))
ts.obj <- ts(observations, start=start, end=end, frequency=365) # daily observations


model.spec <- rugarch:::ugarchspec(
  variance.model = list(
    model = "sGARCH", 
    garchOrder = c(1, 1),
    submodel = NULL,
    external.regressors = NULL,
    variance.targeting = FALSE), 
  mean.model = list(
    armaOrder = c(1, 1), 
    include.mean = FALSE,
    external.regressors = NULL),
    distribution.model = "norm"
  )

model.fit <- rugarch:::ugarchfit(spec=model.spec,
                                data=ts.obj, # the ts object 
                                solver.control = list(trace=0))

forc = rugarch:::ugarchforecast(model.fit, n.ahead = 10)
rugarch:::plot(forc)
```

When I pass this time series to the **rugarch:::ugarchfit** function the timeline starts from 1970-01-01 instead of 1999-05-19, hence the forecast timeline appears shifted in the past and for the wrong year, month and day.

How can I keep the original dates in the forecast plot?

Comment: Please make your example complete: `observations` isn't defined and some call to `ugarchfit` would also help.

Comment: Done. @JuliusVainora

Comment: It is not complete unless we can run it  which we can't from what has been provided.  Cut down `observations` to something minimal yet sufficient to illustrate the problem and show the output of `dput(observations)`.